# Solve the following system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Get the sum of the values of x, y and z

x + 2y - z = 5 (No. 1)
2x - y + z = 2 (No. 2)
y + z = 2 (No. 3)

What I've tried:

**For *y*:**
y + z = 2
y = 2 - z

**For *x*:**
x + 2(2 - z) - z = 5
x + 4 - 2z - z = 5
x - 3z = 5 - 4
x = 1 - 3z

**For *z*:**
2(1 - 3z) - (2 - z) + z = 2
2 - 6z - 2 + z + z = 2
-6z + 2z = 2 + 2 - 2
-4z = 2
z = -0.5

According to my handbook -0.5 isn't the correct answer, not exactly sure where I went wrong..

Comment: They're asking the sum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract $(3)$ from $(2)$ to get $x=y$. Then $(1)+(2)$ gives $4x=7$.

Finally $$x+y+z=\frac74+2.$$

Comment: Can you please show how you subtracted (3) from (2) to get x = y?

Comment: @ErickBoshoff: can't you perform a subtraction ?

Comment: Not for an equation, still learning..

Comment: @ErickBoshoff: subtract member-wise.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you just saved me my weekend! :)

Answer (score 1):

> x - 3z = 5 - 4
>
> x = 1 - 3z

"$x = 1+3z$".